# Coloring even heighten columns

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I try to set different a background colors for left and right columns and to maintain the same height.
So I set a background color for outer wrapper ("container" div) so it will set a color to rightBar.

But this didn't work.
[Online Demo](http://www.webdevout.net/test?018&raw)

I want it to work on all browsers.

Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="contentcontainer">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="mainBar">                  
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>            
       </div>
       <div class="rightBar">                
                    <p>BAR Text BAR Text BAR Text</p>
                    <p>BAR Text BAR Text BAR Text</p>
                    <p>BAR Text BAR Text BAR Text</p>
                    <p>BAR Text BAR Text BAR Text</p>
                    <p>BAR Text BAR Text BAR Text</p>
                    <p>BAR Text BAR Text BAR Text</p>
                    <p>BAR Text BAR Text BAR Text</p>
                    <p>BAR Text BAR Text BAR Text</p>
                    <p>BAR Text BAR Text BAR Text</p>
                    <p>BAR Text BAR Text BAR Text</p>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    font-family: Verdana,Tahoma,Arial, "Trebuchet MS" ,Sans-Serif,Georgia,Courier, "Times New Roman" ,Serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: repeat-x scroll center bottom #C4DAE9;
    text-align:center;
}
.contentcontainer
{

}

.container
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:5px;
    width: 99%;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:Gray;
    clear:both;

}
.mainBar
{

    width:70%;
    float:left;
    background-color:White;

}

.rightBar
{
    width:30%;
    float:left;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By floating your two inner Bars, you take them out of the normal document flow. The result is that the containing box `container` effectively has no content and no height.

By adding a `overflow:hidden` to `.container` you can solve that problem, but then you will run into problems if the right bar is higher than the left bar.

I also think that in order for it to work in IE6, you might need to add a `zoom:1` to `.container` but you'll have to try that.

Comment: In my case the left column is always higher then the right one.

Comment: Because your `.mainBar` will finish before the right column so the white background will not go all the way down.

Comment: Is it possible to fix this issue as well?

Comment: There are pure css solutions like on http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61. Otherwise it´s tables or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the floats at end of the container. One of the ways is:

```
    ...
    <div class="rightBar">
        ...
    </div>
    <br style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.rightBar
{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

also set the height of the parent element "container" to what ever...